# How to keep SelectListItem value selected after submitting form in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, razor-pages, selectlistitem

I'm trying to filter a table using a dropdown-list but I'm not able to keep SelectListItem value selected after submitting the form in ASP.NET Core.

The filter seems to work but whenever the page reloads the selected item is always the same

**Get Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index(int myDropDown)
    {
        var myItems= new List<Items>();

        myItems = _myRepository.GetAllItems();

        var filteredItems = myItems.Where(x => x.Color.DemoId == myDropDown);
        
        if (myDropDown != 0 )
        {
            return View(filteredItems);
        }

        return View(myItems);
    }
```

**Index.chtml**

```
<form asp-controller="MyController">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="myDropDown" 
                asp-items="(_myRepository.GetDemos()).Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
                             { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString()})" onchange="this.form.submit()">

        </select>
    </div>
 </form>
```

**C# Method**

```
    public List<Demo> GetDemos()
    {
        var demos = _dbContext.Demos.Select(x => new Demo()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name
        }).ToList();

        return demos;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying to filter a table using a dropdown-list but I'm not able to keep SelectListItem value selected after submitting the form

You can try to dynamically set `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`, like below.

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="myDropDown"
        asp-items="(_myRepository.GetDemos()).Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                    { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString(), Selected = x.Id == ViewBag.SelectedIndex ? true : false })" onchange="this.form.submit()">
</select>
```

*In action method*

```
public ActionResult Index(int myDropDown)
{
    var myItems = new List<Items>();

    myItems = _myRepository.GetAllItems();

    var filteredItems = myItems.Where(x => x.Color.DemoId == myDropDown);

    //pass selected value through ViewBag etc
    ViewBag.SelectedIndex = myDropDown;

    if (myDropDown != 0)
    {
        return View(filteredItems);
    }

    return View(myItems);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!